# Замена src у iframe без обновления фрейма

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

Всем здравствуйте.
Возникла острая необходимость замены src у фрейма, но так, чтобы сам фрейм не обновлялся. Интерфейс Histоry мне не помог, с адресной строкой работает прекрасно, но с фреймом не захотел (недостаток моих знаний возможно).
Фрейм создается динмически, JS скриптом, с полученным от сервера УРЛ-ом, который, собсно, и надо изменить на любое сочетание букв и цифр, позже будут другие ссылки.
Важно, чтобы зрительно, в инспекторе он заменился, но содержимое осталось, нужна только видимость.
Любые идеи, буду признаетелен.

Comment: Говорят, что можно использовать `.history.replaceState()`, но для этого надо обращаться к `contentWindow` самого `iframe`, но работать будет только со "своим содержимым" `iframe`.

Comment: Так и есть, любая попытка блочится CORS политикой

Comment: Цель примерно такая:
Сейчас <iframe src="blabla" />
А надо <iframe src="bloblo" />
Поговаривают, что можно и вовсе убрать этот атрибут с сохранением контента фрейма, способа не нашел, можно было бы добавить произвольный атрибут и впихнуть в него нужную ссылку

Comment: Цель всё равно не явна. Задача обновить фрейм так, чтобы пользователь не видел момента загрузки обновлённого?

Comment: Нет, не совсем. Задача - сменить src у фрейма, так, чтобы юзер видел другую ссылку в инспекторе. Глубоко копать никто не станет, и если найдут реальную ссылку - ничего страшного, главное, чтобы первая ссылка была та, которую установим

Comment: Подмена ссылки не получится.

Comment: Содержимое фрема получено по сгенерированной ссылке, она одноразовая, в том-то и дело, что обновлять контент не нужно

Comment: Пробовал через file_get_contents() получать html код целевой страницы и передавать через srcdoc во фрейм, содержимое не работает

Answer (score 0):

Задачу решил (?) следующим образом

```
<iframe src="=тут_что_угодно=" 
name="iframe" 
id="iframe" 
allowfullscreen="" 
height="100%" 
width="100%" 
style="border: 0px;" 
srcdoc="<object data=ТУТ_ССЫЛКА_ФРЕЙМА height=100% width=100% type=text/html >
</object>"/>
```

В тег srcdoc фрейма передаю объект с источником из полученной ссылки.
Таким образом атрибут src полностью в моем распоряжении.
Сомнительное решение, но, по сути, цели я достиг.